# plotting a line in matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, perceptron

I have a number of training instances, (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)

I also have a weight vector [w1,w2] of randomly initialized floats between -1 and 1. I would like to plot a line with the equation dotproduct(w,x) which basically has the equation w1xn+w2xn - w0=0. Basically the decision boundary. How would I achieve this in matplotlib without using meshGrid(). In this case its just a line of the form w1xn + w2xn - w0=0 where w0 is a randomly initialized weight again like w1 and w2. I have been thinking about this without much luck and would really appreciate some help on how to implement this a draw the decision boundary (initially before learning). I am using a simple perceptron learning algorithm.

Comment: Is there some machine learning course that just started up?  There seems to be a run of questions like this.  Please see http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html for basic plotting and then edit your question with what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Also, please don't ask multiple almost identical questions.